# Run a for loop to apply a python program on files in a conda prompt

Tags: python, file, for-loop, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to execute a python program on all the .txt of a file on a conda prompt.
The command I use on one file is python extract_rmass_data.py 061206.r.mass > 061206.r.mass_A_data.dat with 061206.r.mass being the original file name and 061206.r.mass_A_data.dat the file in which the filtered data are stocked
So i would like to apply this command on each of the .txt files with a for loop or something, considering only the dates change but they are not regular (sometimes a date is missing)

I've tried somethings but I'm not really familiar with the conda prompt so it's a bit difficult for me ...

Thank you for your help !

Edit :

I ended up modifying the python script I had to just do what I wanted and it worked perfectly. I don't know if what I asked at first is possible or not ...

Comment: What do you mean by "*the conda prompt*"? Is it the standard Python REPL, an IPython kernel, or a system terminal prompt?

Comment: Why not just write a python script? Using the prompt can be tricky, especially for the more complex program you require.

Comment: Assuming 061206 is a date how is it formatted? What is the the range of dates?

Comment: Well it's the classic Anaconda Prompt the one on which you work on your base environment and yes I just thought of modifying the python script instead of trying to do it on the prompt, thank you for your answers

Comment: Can you add an example directory structure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are kinda of describing a task of *shell scripting*. You may want to look that up and the answer really depends on your shell (which is vastly different on Windows and Unix). Or you can solve it by designing it into your Python script, as you've found.